# How to use variables within JSR223 preprocessors in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using two JSR223 preprocessors,in which I want to use variable from one preprocessor into another preprocessor.

how can I use this in Jmeter??

Please assist me with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In the first PreProcessor store some value into a `foo` JMeter Variable using `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

   ```
   vars.put('foo', 'some value')
   ```
2. In the second PreProcessor you can read the value using the same `vars` shorthand like:

   ```
   String myString = vars.get('foo')
   ```

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this `vars` shorthand and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts available for the JSR223 Test Elements

The variable can be seen using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

Comment: Thanks..In the same case if I want to extract response variable from a JSON response and pass the same in next Preprocessor,what should I use??